# understanding what goes in a function

Tags: javascript, function

So I'm trying to learn proper vanilla javascript Instead of relying on frameworks and libraries to do the work for me. The question is: I'm trying to understand what goes into a function when, where and how.

E.G. 
I created some links and a function that has a loop inside that counts the links and should return the number of links and their names. But all I keep getting back is the number of (a) tags.

Can some explain how I get the links names as I've tried innerHTML and the (a) tag. from my understanding and looking at the DOM list I should be able to dig down in the elements to get what I need. I'm assuming I'm just coding it wrong.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    
function loopLinks(links) {
  for (i = links; i < links.length; i++);
  return a.innerHTML;
}

console.log(links);
```

```html
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: why should i be links at the start of your loop? that makes no sense. i should be 0 like the first index of the link array

Comment: Your function has a `for` loop that doesn't do anything, and then returns the `innerHTML` property of an undefined object (`a`).  You also never call your function, so it never executes in the first place.  Honestly, the best thing you could probably do is start with some introductory tutorials.  Currently you're just typing things which look vaguely like code, but you have no sense of the structure of any of this.  Tutorials exist specifically to teach the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earlier posters are correct that your code has some basic structural problems.  I've rewritten it to do what I understand you want to do, with comments explaining what is happening at each step.

I think one of the basic things you might be misunderstanding is the difference between *defining* a function and *invoking* a function.  I've tried to demonstrate that in the comments.

There are many other ways to do this in JavaScript, but this approach is a simple EcmaScript 5 style solution:

```
// this command gets an array of links from the DOM
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// to get the NUMBER of links, just log the length of the array
console.log('Number of links:', links.length);

// here you DEFINE a function that loops over the links.
function loopLinks(links) {     
    // You want to loop over the indicies in the "links" array
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        // get a reference to the link
        let a = links[i];
        // log out the name of each link
        console.log(a.innerHTML);
    }
}

// here, you actually INVOKE(call) the function that loops over the links.
// INVOKING the function makes it run, and outputs your link names. 
loopLinks(links);
```

Best of luck with your foray in to programming.  Don't give up.

Comment: thanks, matt that's what I was trying to do. Things are a lot easier in jquery, but companies don't want that anymore. I think I'm confusing myself.